# What do freeze out and freeze in mean in the context of cosmology?

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics, cosmology, terminology

I have read that when the interaction rate is much greater than the Hubble expansion rate a species is in thermal equilibrium the hot plasma, when the interaction rate fall below the Hubble expansion rate the reaction stops, and the particle species became out of equilibrium and the number density freeze out. Correct me if I am wrong. What is the freeze-in process and what is the difference between them? I am following Kolb and Turner.